# Splice() actually not working in javascript

Tags: javascript, splice

Splice() actually not working in javascript!

```js
const nums = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"];
 
nums.splice(0, 1);
nums.splice(1, 1);
nums.splice(2, 1);

console.log(nums);
```

**But the output I want is this:**

```
[
  "4",
  "5"
]
```

What sholud i do?

Comment: What makes you think it's "not working" - seems to work exactly as [documented](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

Comment: It's the expected output. You are mutating the array, so you need to use the index `0` if you want to splice from the beginning.

Comment: Perhaps you'd be more comfortable with `const lastTwo = nums.slice(-2)`. See [Array.prototype.slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)

Answer (score 5):

It is working exactly intended. Each time you `splice`, you change `nums` and index positions of each element also changes. You can see this if you `console.log` every time you `splice`. You can delete as many elements as you want at once if you just change the parameters a little bit.

```js
const nums = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"];
 
nums.splice(0, 1);
console.log("splice(0,1)", nums);

nums.splice(1, 1);
console.log("splice(1,1)", nums);

nums.splice(2, 1);
console.log("splice(2,1)", nums);

const nums2 = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"];

nums2.splice(0,3);
console.log("splice(0,3)", nums2);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Splice() actually is working in javascript!

Its obvious you don't understand, every time you split the item gets removed and you get a new string what you want to do here is this:

```js
const nums = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"];
 
nums.splice(0, 1);
nums.splice(0, 1);
nums.splice(0, 1);

console.log(nums);
```

Or this:

```js
const nums = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"];
 
nums.splice(0, 3);

console.log(nums);
```

**And the output you want is this:**

```
[
  "4",
  "5"
]
```

This is what you should do.